# Problem with extracting data from Oracle taken from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have data from SQL Server in my Oracle Database  and I have a strange problem.
The data is reported by the administrator.

When I want to have extracting all of columns it's not a problem.

```
Select * from TableMSSQL
```

But where I want extract for example single column I get a message that there is no such column

```
Select Name from TableMSSQL
```

Have any of you encountered such a problem, and what can it result from?

Comment: is there any Name column in that table ?

Comment: can you show structure of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that oracle table can you check `Name`  columns is writed like this : `"Name"`
if it is like this so you can select like this : `select "Name" from TableMSSQL`

Comment: I don't quite understand.You could explain it to me more accurately.

Comment: which part you do not understand?

Comment: Why i should to column give a " " ?

Comment: because the table is created like that. you can check column names